How fast can horse stop in sand or loose soil?
How hard can a horse break? Especially in sand or loose soil?
I think since it can bury it's hooves it can stop much faster than a car.
I did a bit of search and found a couple of papers that talk about horses and friction coefficient like
"Determination of coefficient of friction between the equine foot and different ground surfaces: an in vitro study"
"Grip and Slippage of the Horse’s Hoof on Solid Substrates measured ex Vivo"
but they talk about concrete, tarmac, rubber, etc.

It also has much less momentum than a car. But I don't think this is a pets question as defined here ..

https://physics.stackexchange.com/ perhaps?
